# Parameter to reportlab header using Django

Tags: python, django, reportlab

I'm generating PDF according [this example](http://ericsaupe.com/reportlab-and-django-part-2-headers-and-footers-with-page-numbers/) and works fine, however I have a little problem in the part of header, this is the actual code:

```
def _header_footer(canvas, doc):
    # Save the state of our canvas so we can draw on it
    canvas.saveState()
    styles = getSampleStyleSheet()

    # Header
    header = Paragraph('This is a multi-line header.  It goes on every page.   ' * 5, styles['Normal'])
    w, h = header.wrap(doc.width, doc.topMargin)
    header.drawOn(canvas, doc.leftMargin, doc.height + doc.topMargin - h)

    # Release the canvas
    canvas.restoreState()
```

I want to send data from a model to header, something like this

```
def _header_footer(canvas, doc, custom_data):
    canvas.saveState()
    styles = getSampleStyleSheet()

    header = Paragraph('This is my %s' % custom_data')

    #etc.
```

The _header_footer is called by:

```
doc.build(elements, onFirstPage=self._header_footer, onLaterPages=self._header_footer)
```

How can I send my custom_data variable to _header_footer method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have at least two options here:

You can use [partial from functools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial) which allow to "bind" some arguments to your function. For instance:

```
from functools import partial
def _header_footer(canvas, doc, custom_data):
    ...

# Usage:
doc.build(elements, onFirstPage=partial(_header_footer, custom_data=my_custom_data))
```

Or since you appeared to be using this inside a class, due to the `self` keyword (or is it a typo?), you can simply have `custom_data` as an attribute to your class.

```
class MyPdf(object):
    def __init__(self, custom_data):
        self.custom_data = custom_data
        self.doc = ... # your doc

    def _header_footer(self, canvas, doc):
        # you can access self.custom_data here
        ...

    def build(self):
        ...
        self.doc.build(elements, onFirstPage=self._header_footer)

# Usage
my_pdf = MyPdf(custom_data)
my_pdf.build()
```

Comment: Accepted, but is partial instead partials :)

Comment: @SébastienDeprez you saved me with 'partial'